# HTML/JavaScript Button - link to a URL, that is being stored as a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building a HTML page, and as part of the page, I have a button which links to a different page, which is set as a variable in AngularJS.

Here is the example of the current button I have which isn't working:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open({{profile.link}})" value="Go to Profile"/>
```

Obviously, depending on the user, the link changes - meaning that I can not have a fixed variable.

This is also to be run on localhost:8000, and will open to an external page on the Internet.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

p.s. There's nothing wrong with the {{profile.link}}, as I have tested this and it has the correct value.

Comment: Why can't you have a simple `a` tag there?

Comment: @AudriusLubys I could do, but I'd prefer a button if I'm honest... That's definitely my backup plan though

Comment: @James did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you mean that the link should not be changed per user, right? In this case it's possible to declare a "link variable" in another place (it could be different angular scope, in root scope and etc.)

Please try something like the following:

```
    <input type="button" onclick="window.open({{someanotherscope.link}})" value="Go to Profile"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-click="window.open (profile.link)" instead  of onclick

Answer (score 0):

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/797/)**

```js
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('testController', ['$scope','$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.profile = { "link": 'http://www.google.com'};
    $scope.openWindow = function() {
        $window.open($scope.profile.link, 'Title', 'width=500,height=400');
    };}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
    <input type="button" ng-click="openWindow()" value="Go to Profile"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please stop writting with $scope its not professional!!!
Read this :
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1